# npm can not install github repo

Tags: reactjs, npm

I run this command to install videojs-sublime-inspired-skin,

```
npm install --save https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git
```

but, error occures, i don't know what happen.

```
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /var/folders/g9/3z4g_fqs5z5_w73rc09lkb0w0000gn/T/npm-21125-341144dd/git-cache-481a340a/25a23c1fc3743b5b205d70e27f379c6045752783
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -21
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/huangzhenjun/Public/Git/PartTime/x-video/npm-debug.log
➜  x-video git:(master) ✗ npm install https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /var/folders/g9/3z4g_fqs5z5_w73rc09lkb0w0000gn/T/npm-21234-c0865e1d/git-cache-d0829176/25a23c1fc3743b5b205d70e27f379c6045752783
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -21
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/huangzhenjun/Public/Git/PartTime/x-video/npm-debug.log
```

here is my env:

npm: 3.10.8

node: 6.9.1

update npm-debug.log:

i flow the guide from npm doc, but i don't know why it can not work.

here is the all log recored in /Users/huangzhenjun/Public/Git/PartTime/x-video/npm-debug.log.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save',
1 verbose cli   'https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.8
3 info using node@v6.9.1
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git
8 silly fetchOtherPackageData https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git
9 silly cache add args [ 'https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git',
9 silly cache add   null ]
10 verbose cache add spec https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git
11 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
11 silly cache add   raw: 'https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git',
11 silly cache add   scope: null,
11 silly cache add   escapedName: null,
11 silly cache add   name: null,
11 silly cache add   rawSpec: 'https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git',
11 silly cache add   spec: 'git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git',
11 silly cache add   type: 'hosted',
11 silly cache add   hosted:
11 silly cache add    { type: 'github',
11 silly cache add      ssh: 'git@github.com:zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git',
11 silly cache add      sshUrl: 'git+ssh://git@github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git',
11 silly cache add      httpsUrl: 'git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git',
11 silly cache add      gitUrl: 'git://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git',
11 silly cache add      shortcut: 'github:zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin',
11 silly cache add      directUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin/master/package.json' } }
12 verbose addRemoteGit caching https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git
13 verbose addRemoteGit git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git is a repository hosted by github
14 silly tryClone cloning git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git via git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git
15 verbose tryClone git-https-github-com-zanechua-videojs-sublime-inspired-skin-git-b4259c0f not in flight; caching
16 verbose correctMkdir /Users/huangzhenjun/.npm/_git-remotes correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
17 verbose makeDirectory /Users/huangzhenjun/.npm/_git-remotes creation not in flight; initializing
18 silly makeDirectory /Users/huangzhenjun/.npm/_git-remotes uid: 501 gid: 20
19 info git [ 'clone',
19 info git   '--template=/Users/huangzhenjun/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates',
19 info git   '--mirror',
19 info git   'https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git',
19 info git   '/Users/huangzhenjun/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-zanechua-videojs-sublime-inspired-skin-git-b4259c0f' ]
20 verbose mirrorRemote git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git git clone https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git
21 verbose correctMkdir /Users/huangzhenjun/.npm/_git-remotes correctMkdir not in flight; initializing
22 verbose setPermissions git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git set permissions on /Users/huangzhenjun/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-zanechua-videojs-sublime-inspired-skin-git-b4259c0f
23 verbose resolveHead git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git original treeish: master
24 info git [ 'rev-list', '-n1', 'master' ]
25 silly resolveHead git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git resolved treeish: 25a23c1fc3743b5b205d70e27f379c6045752783
26 verbose resolveHead git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git resolved Git URL: git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git#25a23c1fc3743b5b205d70e27f379c6045752783
27 silly resolveHead Git working directory: /var/folders/g9/3z4g_fqs5z5_w73rc09lkb0w0000gn/T/npm-21832-93e8ecce/git-cache-04482398/25a23c1fc3743b5b205d70e27f379c6045752783
28 info git [ 'clone',
28 info git   '/Users/huangzhenjun/.npm/_git-remotes/git-https-github-com-zanechua-videojs-sublime-inspired-skin-git-b4259c0f',
28 info git   '/var/folders/g9/3z4g_fqs5z5_w73rc09lkb0w0000gn/T/npm-21832-93e8ecce/git-cache-04482398/25a23c1fc3743b5b205d70e27f379c6045752783' ]
29 verbose cloneResolved git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git clone Cloning into '/var/folders/g9/3z4g_fqs5z5_w73rc09lkb0w0000gn/T/npm-21832-93e8ecce/git-cache-04482398/25a23c1fc3743b5b205d70e27f379c6045752783'...
29 verbose cloneResolved done.
30 info git [ 'checkout', '25a23c1fc3743b5b205d70e27f379c6045752783' ]
31 verbose checkoutTreeish git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git checkout Note: checking out '25a23c1fc3743b5b205d70e27f379c6045752783'.
31 verbose checkoutTreeish
31 verbose checkoutTreeish You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
31 verbose checkoutTreeish changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
31 verbose checkoutTreeish state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.
31 verbose checkoutTreeish
31 verbose checkoutTreeish If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
31 verbose checkoutTreeish do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:
31 verbose checkoutTreeish
31 verbose checkoutTreeish   git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
31 verbose checkoutTreeish
31 verbose checkoutTreeish HEAD is now at 25a23c1... Regression fix for Minified CSS
32 info git [ 'submodule', '-q', 'update', '--init', '--recursive' ]
33 verbose updateSubmodules git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git submodule update
34 error addLocal Could not install /var/folders/g9/3z4g_fqs5z5_w73rc09lkb0w0000gn/T/npm-21832-93e8ecce/git-cache-04482398/25a23c1fc3743b5b205d70e27f379c6045752783
35 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
35 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native)
35 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git { Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
35 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Error (native) errno: -21, code: 'EISDIR', syscall: 'read' }
36 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
37 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
38 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
39 silly install printInstalled
40 verbose stack Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
40 verbose stack     at Error (native)
41 verbose cwd /Users/huangzhenjun/Public/Git/PartTime/x-video
42 error Darwin 16.7.0
43 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git"
44 error node v6.9.1
45 error npm  v3.10.8
46 error code EISDIR
47 error errno -21
48 error syscall read
49 error eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
50 error eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
50 error eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
50 error eisdir a package you are trying to install.
51 verbose exit [ -21, true ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

videojs-sublime-inspired-skin repo doesn't have package.json file. Npm need to package.json file of that package to install. That is first issue you should resolve.

If you are owner of this repo, you can add package file (on repo directory) via :

> npm init

After adding package.json file to this repo, you should run the command like this:

> npm install git+https://github.com/zanechua/videojs-sublime-inspired-skin.git --save

Also the other examples of installation methods and example at this page.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Are you running multiple npm installs at the same time? npm doesn't like this, as it allocates one temporary work area, and the path suggests it has found a problem here.

The other option is that you have corruption, and you could do an `npm rebuild` or simply `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install` which might fix it

Comment: I tried  both 'npm build' and 'rm -rf node_modules && npm install', but it still not work.

Comment: I think the package is incomplete @fatih-ayyildiz is on the right track with the missing package.json If you want to install it, you can probably just copy the css files into your project